# How to upload Magento 1.9 sql file on WAMP localhost

Tags: mysql, magento, installation

I have a problem with uploading sample data sql file in phpMyAdmin database on localhost. When I try to upload, it uploads for about 3-5 minutes, and then tells me "Script timeout passed, if you want to finish import, please resubmit same file and import will resume"... when i try that, same thing happens... then i check tables, and see that many tables missing (sometimes upload about 100 tables, sometimes, 200)  I changed php.ini file, and restarted wamp, but I get same results. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You could also use MySql console to import sql files. Sample commands:

```
mysql> use db_name;
mysql> source c:/path/to/your/file.sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following code

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;
```

in your phpmyadmin config.inc.php and it will solve your timeout problem, this should work on both XAMPP and WAMP

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to solve this problem............

Click on the WAMP icon right next to time on your desktop.

Goto PHP > php.ini

php.ini file will open.

Now search for following variables in the file and change the values as given below

```
post_max_size = 750M

upload_max_filesize = 750M

max_execution_time = 300

max_input_time = 540

memory_limit = 1000M
```

Save and close the php.ini file.

Restart the WAMP server via the WAMP icon on the system tray, the option is called Restart all Services.

This should import a large .sql file.

Answer (score 0):

Uploading sample data should not take that much time. Consider downloading another sample data sql from magento site and try again.Sometimes these types of problem occurs.

Try this out if above mentioned methods didn't help.

Hope this will work.